# excel: comparing values of several columns

Tags: excel, comparison

I have some data (say hits) for different cache size say 1M, 2M, 4M in three columns. I want to see Hits(1M) < Hits(2M) < Hits(4M). One way is to write two comparison operations, but I have many columns. Is there a way to check for something like 'ascending' order relationship between columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many rows are you dealing with?

One solution (if you're not dealing with an overwhelmingly large number of rows) would be to take each row, and add the headers of each column above it, and then sort each row along with its own set of headers (which would be a two-row sort across all your columns).  The resulting order of each header row would give you your desired answer.

Comment: I have 26 rows as hit values for 3-4 cache sizes. One cache size is one column.